# How to CONCAT 0 with number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2  input box value `"bill_amount" with value 1250, "xray" with value 0

when i tried to find the sum  it returns 12500 but when i tried to find the subtracted value it returns 1250 . why for addition it concat 0 while subtraction not including 0.

And how to avoid that?

```
 console.log( document.getElementById("bill_amount").value-document.getElementById("xray").value);
```

Comment: Cast it to the number before performing arithmetic  operations. Use `Number(value)` or simply `+value`

Comment: I think your value will be in string format so use parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your values using `parseFloat()`:

```js
function calculate() {
  console.log(parseFloat(document.getElementById("bill_amount").value) - parseFloat(document.getElementById("xray").value));
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='bill_amount' />
<input type='text' id='xray' />
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

*-* converts strings to numbers:

```
"1250" - "0" => 1250
```

*+* does not:

```
"1250" + "0" => "12500"
```

So may convert first:

```
+"1250" +" 0" => 1250
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your values as numbers:

```js
var billAmount = document.getElementById("bill_amount");
var xray = document.getElementById("xray");
var calculate = document.getElementById("calculate");

calculate.onclick = function() {
  console.log(parseFloat(billAmount.value, 10) - parseFloat(xray.value, 10));
}
```

```html
<input id="bill_amount" type="number" min="0" value="1250" step="0.0001"/>
<input id="xray" type="number" min="0" value="0" step="0.0001"/>
<input id="calculate" type="button" value="calculate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 console.log(eval( document.getElementById("bill_amount").value-document.getElementById("xray").value));
```

Try this